# How do I solve this indefinite integral?

Tags: improper-integrals

Given the improper integral: $$\int_1^\infty 45\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x} \, dx$$
I was able to set up the limits as shown below, but I am not sure how to continue integrating.
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_1^t 45\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x} \, dx = \lim_{t\to\infty} 45 \int_1^t \frac{x+1}{x^2+2x} \, dx$$

Comment: $$\begin{align} u & = x^2+2x \\ du & = (2x+2) \, dx \\  du/2 & = (x+1) \, dx \end{align}$$ $$ \int_1^t \frac{x+1}{x^2+2x}\,dx = \int_3^{t^2+2t} \frac{du/2} u $$

Comment: Easiest way to integrate is using partial fractions $\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x}=\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2(2+x)}$

Comment: Doesn't it diverge?

Comment: Thanks, and yes it does diverge.

Comment: In which case there is no answer

Answer (score 1):

By $u$-substitution, $u=x^2+2x.$